# Where can I find a shallow-water solver in MATLAB?

Tags: oceanography, models, homework, matlab

I do not know how to solve the shallow water equations in the matrix form in MATLAB. I didn't find anything useful on the internet. I have the specific mathematical equations to solve (please see the picture below) and I must write in MATLAB. If someone has examples, I would appreciate it.

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - f\nu + g \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x} = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial t} + fu + g\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial y}=0$$

$$\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial t}+H\big(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \nu}{\partial y}\big)=0$$

Comment: Have you tried coding it yourself? What you are asking for is a solver, but you need boundary conditions and initial conditions to solve it. 
Try the Runge-Kutta integration in time. For your spatial derivatives, you may want a finite differencing method. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Runge-KuttaMethod.html

Comment: https://lmgtfy.com/?q=shallow+water+equations+in+the+matrix+form+in+MATLAB

Comment: This certainly sounds like a homework question I had at university too... you learn by doing, not from someone else's work :-)

Answer (score 4):

You aren't supposed to do link only answers, but that is really all this questions deserves. Did you look on Google? I did.

https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/shallow_water_1d/shallow_water_1d.html

http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/paul.connolly/teaching/practicals/shallow_water_equations.html

http://sanders.eng.uci.edu/matlabcodes.html

Those were 3 of the first 9 hits on google, and they all have code examples. There is no close option due to lack of effort, but I'll give it a downvote.